# MUD-based game books?

Tags: publishing

Is there much crossover between published RPGs and the MUDs of old?

I am looking for specific examples of MUDs that were later published as game books.

Comment: Interesting. Are you looking for MUDs as settings, MUDs from established settings, or MUD like mechanics?

Comment: "MUDs of old" is a strange term.  There are many MUDS still around today, some with thousands of users.  I know of many books and games turned into MUDS, but not many MUDS turned into books.  I would try http://www.mudconnect.com/index.html if you are looking for something specific.

Comment: Also, can you explain the megadungeon tag in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everquest was based off of Diku codebase (even if they deny it.) They made a tabletop rpg.  This is the only one I can think of that was released with any real distribution.  I Remember there were a few of the larger realms that made it from MUD to G(raphical)MUD but the tech wasnt really there to do what we wanted in a web page at the time.  I know of a few short stories and even amature novellas were written about some of the MUDS.  But most of them existed only on Newsgroups and BBS's.  Most of the effort that went into the mud was to make more content or tweak code/add new functionality.  Most of the logic and math used for it would be to complicated to replicate at the table top level.  Its much easier for a computer to manage thousands of HP and 20 hits per second than a GM.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the crossover goes the other way - people implementing D&D or BRP  in their MUD's codebase.

I've never heard of it going the other way.

Comment: I could possibly see the setting of a MUD being published as a module for an RPG with suitable mechanics. Unfortunately, I still don't know of any.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count World of Warcraft and Dragon Age as MUDs (I don't, but you might), then count it among the online worlds that have gone from virtual to tabletop.